# Prove that the resolvent set of an operator is an open set

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory, spectral-theory

I need to prove that the resolvent set of the operator $T$ , is an open set. I saw the proof in the book of Bernard Beauzamy and I understand the work done there except one part.

The proposition states that the resolvent set of an operator is an open set.

Proof:
We fix $\lambda \in \rho(T)$ and let $\varepsilon \in \mathbb{C}$, with $|\varepsilon|<\frac{1}{||R(\lambda)||}$. We will show that $\lambda +\varepsilon \in \rho(T)$.

I do not see why $\lambda +\varepsilon \in \rho(T)$ implies that $\rho(T)$ is open.

Thank you for helping!

Comment: It shows that the open disk of radius $\frac{1}{||R(\lambda)||}$ and center $\lambda$ is contained in $\rho(T)$.

Comment: Yes, it is clear to me now. Thank you a lot :)